# C++ regex to get scopes delimited by level 0 square brackets

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, scope, delimiter

Consider the following C++11 code to test C++ regex:

```
// GPLv3 - Vincent R. - 2015
// Compilation:  g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 regex.cpp -o regex
// Execution: ./regex "my_regex" "my_string"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string regex(argc > 1 ? std::string(argv[1]) : std::string());
    std::string string(argc > 2 ? std::string(argv[2]) : std::string());
    std::cout<<"REGEX = "<<regex<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"STRING = "<<string<<std::endl;
    std::regex rgx(regex);
    auto begin = std::sregex_iterator(string.begin(), string.end(), rgx);
    auto end = std::sregex_iterator();
    std::cout<<"RESULTS = "<<std::distance(begin, end)<<std::endl;
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout<<it->str()<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It executes a provided regex on a provided string.

Now, consider the following string:

```
\(abcd.1 '[' \[ [ef([)gh-] [ijk(])\)l*] mnop
```

I want to search for "scopes" of level 0 delimited by square brackets `[` and `]` so that the result will be:

- `[ef([)gh-]`
- `[ijk(])\)l*]`

To obtain that, here are the steps:

1. The search has to ignore escaped delimiters: `\[`, `\]`, `\(`, `\)`, `\{`, `\}`, `\<`, `\>`, `\"`, `\'`
2. Matches separately the most extended groups starting by `[` and ending by `]`, ignoring brackets that are inside other pair of delimiters `()`, `{}`, `<>`, `""`, and `''`

**EDIT:**

As regex don't do recusion as noted in the comment, how to matches :

- `[ef([)gh-]`
- `[ijk(])\)l*]`

from

```
\(abcd.1 \[ [ef([)gh-] [ijk(])\)l*] mnop
```

only ignoring escaped `\[` and `\]`

Comment: Regular expressions don't do recursion; they can't keep track of nesting level. In other words, a grammar that involves possibly-nested pairs of delimiters is not [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar). If you are sure input string doesn't contain nested delimiters (or, more generally, has them nested to no more than some known depth) then it's possible, in principle, to construct the regular expression you want - but it would be a monster hundreds of characters in length. It would be faster and easier to write a special-purpose parser.

Comment: If you only ignore `\[` and `\]`, you would end up with `[ijk(]`, won't you? Also, in your grammar, is `\\ ` a valid escape sequence? In other words, when given a string `[\\]x]`, should the program produce `[\\]` or `[\\]x]`? Is the leftmost closing bracket considered escaped?